# THREE.js float precision skinned animation

Tags: animation, three.js, precision

I noticed issues with skinned animations on larger world-coordinates. The bones start to jump around more frequently and distant the larger the coordinates go.

On iPad the issue already appears at 200 units, slightly precision issue, drastically increasing moving further, so it seems like precision is even less. On Desktop it starts vibrating at 400,000 units.  I'm using a 1 unit/1 meter scale, that is recommended. If i scale everything up immensely (1000x) the issue starts to disappear, but that isn't really a solution to go with.

The shader already declares `precision highp float`, i don't know if there is anything fixing the issue.

Is there any solution i don't need to scale up everything and need to clamp the world coordinates within a very low range?

Comment: I think the precision problems are because your coordinates are so small. There's not a ton of precision when you only use the low end of what floating point variables are capable of representing, and rounding errors compound faster. Yes, scale everything up and your problems should disappear. Most important though is that you use a scale which has room for both your largest and smallest distances. If you have a large object with a unit size of "1", the fine detail in that object can't be represented well, and jittering will occur in its geometry.

Comment: I really wonder why this already occurs at 400,000 units, does JS use half float? On regular desktop software there is no issue down to 6 decimal digits, no matter if it's several million units away. 

I guess i have to scale it up. I really need to know a "optimal scale to go", i don't want to have hundreds of assets to rescale at some point.